# Could this be a zero-length partition? Recover External HDD

Tags: partitioning, files

I can see my external hdd. I can mount it and see the folders. However, I cannot open the files. I got an error splicing files I/O. that it cannot open file.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I`ve tried thoses command following the answers of the forum:

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb1

fsck from util-linux 2.27.1

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sdb1

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo dumpe2fs -f /dev/sdb1 | grep -i superblock

dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

dumpe2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb1

mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

Creating filesystem with 122096389 4k blocks and 30531584 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 30593375-6af1-4668-a808-7730a09dcd9e
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 /dev/sdb1

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while 
trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  mke2fs -n /dev/sdb1

mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

Creating filesystem with 122096389 4k blocks and 30531584 inodes

Filesystem UUID: 59e19e76-7f2e-4676-a744-b8f6a9e2fa43

Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  e2fsck -f -b 8193 /dev/sdb1

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while 
trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/disk2/backup-sdb1.img
dd: failed to open '/disk2/backup-sdb1.img': No such file or directory

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sdb1

mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

Creating filesystem with 122096389 4k blocks and 30531584 inodes

Filesystem UUID: f0d78289-4e5d-40ee-a771-903ba6cd8151

Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$  fsck.ext4 -n -b 32768 /dev/sdb1

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while 
trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

Any help to guide me to get back my hard drive would be great. Thank you,

Comment: Edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted view of /dev/sdb, and of `fdisk -l` and/or `gdisk -l /dev/sdb`and/or `sudo lsblk`.